# How does the Angular team manage feature flags in the framework?

Tags: angular, release-management, code-documentation, sdlc, feature-flags

The [Angular](https://angular.io) team uses a website to document upgrades

https://update.angular.io/

In that website, one can select how to upgrade from version to version and it displays a detailed list of steps to follow.

I'm insterested to know the process the team follows to document it specially around "feature flags", from introducing it in the code to documenting it in the website. Is it an automatic process? Do they use any third party software other than the tools in github?

Comment: Which feature flags are you referring to?

Comment: any flag to activate features, e.g. like when they rolled out ivy, you needed to switch on the flag  enableIvy to true. I’m interested to know how they document them and keep track as adding feature flags in a product could become quiet messy. I know there are apps to manage that like launchdarkly, i’m particularly interested to know how the angular team handles them